# I want to use the Delete route, but it is not supported. How can I use this route?

Tags: php

I want to delete the record selected from the index list, but I'm having trouble using deleteRoute

web.php

```
Route::delete('/destroy/{id}', 'ProjectController@destroy')->name('despro');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    Project::destroy($id);
    return redirect('/project');
}
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($view as $v)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$v->id}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{route('workindex', ['id' => $v->id])}}">{{$v->project_name}}</a></td>
        <td>{{$v->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->division}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->content}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->date}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->preferred_date}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->user_name}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($cats as $cat)
                @if($v->category_id == $cat->id)
                    {{$cat->name}}
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </td>
        <td>{{$v->status}}</td>
        <td>{{$v->estimated_work_time}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{url('/destroy', ['id' => $v->id])}}">delete</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Will be deleted and redirected to index.blade.php　but
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.
Come out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete route require **DELETE** method.

**If you're using Laravel 5.1 or later**

```
<form action="{{ route('despro', ['id' => $v->id]) }}" method="POST">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button>delete</button>
</form>
```

**If you're using Laravel 5.6 or later then**

```
 <form action="{{ route('despro', ['id' => $v->id]) }}" method="POST">
        @method('DELETE')
        @csrf
        <button>delete</button>
    </form>
```